# Cron log shows sh: 1: hdfs: not found

Tags: python, hadoop, scripting

I am writing a housekeeping script with python that stores files that are 3 days old into hdfs which works normally but it doesnt work with cron.

Here's my code

```
#storing the files from archive to hdfs within directory - tmp-Archive
if os.system('hdfs dfs -test -e /user/hadoop/tmp-archive') == 0:
    print('Archive location exists...using current archive.')
else:
    os.system('hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hadoop/tmp-archive')
    print('Archive created -> /user/hadoop/tmp-archive')
archive_file_list = os.listdir('/home/hadoop/PycharmProjects/Housekeeping-Script--master/Archive')
for j in archive_file_list:                             #checks files within archive and stores it in hdfs
    archive_file_dir = '/home/hadoop/PycharmProjects/Housekeeping-Script--master/Archive/' + j
    os.system('hdfs dfs -put {} /user/hadoop/tmp-archive'.format(archive_file_dir)) 
print('Files added to HDFS in dir : /user/hadoop/tmp-archive')
```

crontab:

```
* * * * * python /home/hadoop/PycharmProjects/Housekeeping-Script--master/housekeeper.py > /home/hadoop/PycharmProjects/Housekeeping-Script--master/Logs/`date +\%d\%m\%Y\%H\%M`-cron.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that you `hdfs` is in a location that is added to your `PATH` in a file like `.profile`, which won't run through cron.

You could add it manually at the start of your script, or use absolute paths to `hdfs`. You can run `which hdfs` to find the absolute path.

---

Let's assume, `hdfs` is located in `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/bin`. In this case, `which hdfs` will show you `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/bin/hdfs`. (If your path is different, change all the following references to the path according to your output of `which hdfs`.)

Now you can either add this at the start of your script...

```py
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ':/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/bin'
```

...or use the absolute path to `hdfs` in your script...

```py
os.system('/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hadoop/tmp-archive')
```

...or, if you wanted to avoid hardcoding the path inside the python script itself, you could either pass the path in as a command line argument or an environment variable (so you would set it in the crontab file), or you could create a bash script that sets the correct `PATH` and then calls your python script, and call that bash script from cron.

Unfortunately, just prepending `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/bin` in your script invocation in the crontab file won't work because cron will not expand variables at the right side of the assignment. But another way around that would be to use something like `sh -c 'PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/bin python /path/to/my/script.py'` as command.

Comment: using the os.environ['PATH'] didnt work but using the absolute path to hdfs worked. In my case it was : os.system('/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hadoop/tmp-archive')

Answer (score 2):

The reason could be the path of HDFS is not being able to fetch properly, please check if you have set the PATH at the beginning of the cron file.